# mongodrop slow on small db

Tags: integration-testing

I'm using a real Mongo instance for my integration tests. On every test, I call `mongorestore my_db_state --drop` because I need a clean db to start the next test.

On my tiny db (with only one test user account) it takes 180 ms to run `mongorestore my_db_state` (without `--drop`) and `455 ms` with `--drop`.

I don't understand why it's taking so long to drop the db, but how can I speed this up?

I may have a bunch of different connections on the mongo server because I never close them on my Flask server, but they probably should be closed after the test is over...just not sure if this is an issue to care about.

Is there a faster way to restore a snapshot to its original state for testing purposes?

Comment: Does mongorestore on its own not properly restore the database to its proper state? I don't see why you need to drop the database just to recreate unless you don't have confidence that mongorestore is working properly.

Comment: Unfortunately, no it doesn't. It won't overwrite documents with matching _ids, it will only insert atop what's already there.

Comment: Very interesting - I wonder if that's intentional or not. While this is certainly on topic as an SQA problem, I wonder if it isn't worth asking the question on dba.stackexchange as well, from a different perspective. This is about speeding up your tests - any option to speed up your tests works for you. But you could ask the dba folks about how to reset the database faster than `--drop` - perfectly allowable since they approach from different perspectives!

Comment: @corsiKa thanks will do